# Убрать кнопку расширения в Toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

Можно ли убрать эту кнопку в ToolBar если они не требуется в данной ситуации?

[image: ToolBar]

Answer (score 4):

WPF хорош тем, что все элементы в нем имеют свой стиль, который очень легко можно изменить!

1. Создадим пустой элемент, просто напишем в XAML `<ToolBar/>`.
2. В конструкторе (окно, где мы видим наше приложение) жмем на наш элемент правой кнопкой мышь.
3. Жмем в выпадающем меню "Правка шаблона" - "Правка копии". У нас появится данное окно:

[image: Edit Window]

4. Указываем в данном окне имя стиля, а также путь, где он будет создан.
5. У вас будет создан весь дизайн данного контрола, который вы можете легко отредактировать! Давайте уберем кнопку:

   - Нам необходимо найти элемент с именем `OverflowGrid`, это обычный Grid (`<Grid x:Name="OverflowGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Right">`). Вы можете отредактировать его, можете скрыть, а можете удалить его и все, что с ним связано. Я лично скрою, допишу просто `Visibility="Collapsed"`.
   - После скрытия этого Grid вы увидите, что справа будет отступ, его тоже стоит убрать. Находится он у элемента с именем `MainPanelBorder`. Находим его и видим, что он ссылается на стиль `ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle`, находим его и там видим `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,11,0"/>`, ставим значение в 0 или вовсе удаляем строку.

Вот и все, теперь мы можем применить этот стиль к любому ToolBar и он будет без кнопки:

[image: Result]

Вот таким простым способом вы можете изменять стиль любого контрола в WPF. Удачи в программирование!

---

Еще один способ (как по мне, не очень хороший, ибо работаем со стилями через код) [[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051264/6808809)].

1. Подписываем наш ToolBar на событие `Loaded`.
2. В обработчике выполняем тоже, что мы делали через XAML:

   ```
   private void ToolBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       ToolBar toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
       var overflowGrid = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
       if (overflowGrid != null)
       {
           overflowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
       }
       var mainPanelBorder = toolBar.Template.FindName("MainPanelBorder", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
       if (mainPanelBorder != null)
       {
           mainPanelBorder.Margin = new Thickness();
       }
   }
   ```