# C# WPF ComboBox ToggleButton BorderThickness

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, design

Как изменить BorderThickness для ComboBox ToggleButton?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я недавно отвечал на вопрос, где показывал как редактировать стили нужного элемента. По той же инструкции вполне можно и изменить то, что вы хотите. Сам ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840623/Убрать-кнопку-расширения-в-toolbar/840643#840643).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нету в стиле BorderThickness свойства)

Comment: ну в шаблоне-то есть какой-нибудь `Border`: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates меняйте свойство у него